# Can I use widget of application that installed to sd-card

Tags: android, widget, sd-card

I created my own widget. On default my app installs to sd-storage. In this case i can not use widget. It works only when i move app to device memory. But i don't want to do so. Is it possible to use widget from sd-card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is a system requirement.

[Applications That Should NOT Install on External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot)